# How to select top 100 (table) then limit the display

Tags: php, mysql

I have 22,000 entries in my table, so I used `limit` when displaying my table, Then a user can define how many rows to be displayed:

[image]

My problem is, even when I type smaller digit like 10 it displays 10 entries only but it loads my entire table row per row, taking almost 30 seconds to load.

```
$rpp = 10;
$page = 1;
$temp = ($page-1)*$rpp;
$query = " SELECT * FROM table_me ORDER by date_sourced desc LIMIT $temp, $rpp ";
$page_result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
```

I tried this, and followed the instructions but this doesn't work giving me error: `SELECT TOP 300 * FROM table_me LIMIT 0, 25`

```
$query = " SELECT  TOP 300 * FROM table_me ORDER by date_sourced desc LIMIT $temp, $rpp ";
```

How can I load 300 only from my table but still gives me access for the remaining bottom values in table?

Then this is my code to echo values from table:

```
<?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($page_result)) { $currsamp_id = $row['id'];?>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><input class="ui checkbox" type="checkbox" name="check_box" value="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>"></td>
                                    <td onclick="$('#options_<?php echo $currsamp_id ?>').dropdown('show')" style="overflow: visible !important;"> 
                                        <div class="ui dropdown item" id="options_<?php echo $currsamp_id ?>">
                                            <i class="settings icon"></i><i class="dropdown icon"></i>
                                            <div class="menu">
                                                <?php
                                                    if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
                                                        $temp = $row['id'];
                                                        $ds = $row['date_sourced']; $sh = $row['sha1']; $vsdt = $row['vsdt']; $tx = $row['trendx'];  $n = str_replace('\"', '\\\"', $row['notes']);
                                                        echo "<a class='item' style='color: black; width: 100%;' onclick='open_update(\"" . $temp . "\", \"" . $ds . "\", \"" . $sh . "\", \"" . $vsdt . "\",  \"" . $tx . "\",  \"" . $n . "\")'>Update</a>";
                                                    } else {
                                                        echo '<a class="item modal_trigger" style="color: black; width: 100%;" data-target="#modal_login">Update</a>';
                                                    }
                                                ?>
                                                <?php
                                                    if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
                                                        $temp = $row['id']; $sha1 = $row['sha1'];
                                                        echo '<a class="item" style="color: black;" onclick="open_delete(\''.$temp.'\', \''.$sha1.'\', \'open\')">Delete</a>';
                                                    } else {
                                                        echo '<a class="item modal_trigger" style="color: black;" data-target="#modal_login">Delete</a>';
                                                    }
                                                ?>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td nowrap title="Date Sourced"><?php echo $row['date_sourced'] ?></td>
                                    <td nowrap title="SHA-1"><?php echo $row['sha1'] ?></td>
                                    <td nowrap title="VSDT"><?php echo $row['vsdt'] ?></td>
                                    <td nowrap title="TrendX"><?php echo $row['trendx'] ?></td>
                                    <td nowrap title="Notes"><?php echo $row['notes'] ?></td>
                                </tr>
                            <?php } ?>
```

Comment: I suggest adding an appropriate index to the column `date_sourced`, this should speed up the sorting. The second query looks like it won't work for any DBMS, since `select top` works in Microsoft world but `limit` doesn't

Comment: You are mixing syntax of two DBMS `mysql` and `sql server`. If you are using `mysql` as you tagged it then use `limit`.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments you are mixing the syntax from two different DBMS.

For **mysql** use `LIMIT`, not `TOP`. Also, `LIMIT` has only one parameter, not two.

Here is your corrected query:

```
$query = " SELECT * FROM table_me ORDER BY date_sourced DESC LIMIT 100 ";
```

This will return the top 100 rows only.

Comment: i tried this but it still loads for 30 secs but it does show only 100 entries

Comment: do you have an index on  `date_sourced`?

Comment: yes I do have, I don't know why does it loads slowly

Comment: that is really weird. can you maybe add the rest of your PHP code to the question. Maybe there is an another issue somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Also – if you need to find the top ten `date_sourced` *quickly,* you should create an index on that column.

Otherwise, yes, the DBMS has no choice but to scan the entire table, finding the top entries, before delivering the first *n* of those rows to you!

In the presence of an index, such a query will be virtually instantaneous.

Comment: i created an index to it, but still loads almost 30 secs

Comment: Use the `EXPLAIN` verb to see how MySQL is interpreting that query.  This will give you the "execution plan," which is the actual stuff that drives the results engine.

Answer (score 0):

I'll make this another "answer" ...

Use the `EXPLAIN` verb to see exactly how the RDBMS will run the query, *e.g.:*

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM table_me ORDER BY date_sourced DESC LIMIT 100
```

This will give you the so-called "execution plan," which is what actually drives the query engine.  (The RBMS "compiles" the SQL, considers various statistics, and comes up with a plan.  It does this for every query.)

`EXPLAIN` causes the RDBMS to return the plan to you instead of subsequently executing it.  This tells you exactly *how* the RDBMS intended to get the answer that you seek.

If a query runs "unexpectedly slowly," this is a good way to find out why.  *(The format of the plan-data varies considerably from one RDBMS to another.)*